# MS Access 2007 VBA - Can I Add font properties in VB Format$ function

Tags: ms-access, vba, automation, ms-access-2007

so if I have a DAO recordset returing values, and I use Format$, is there a way to set the font property of what is only contained within the Format$ portion?

For example I have this:

```
"Metric #43 = " & Format$(rs!Metric43, "Yes/No")
```

so this is actually for ppt automation, not an access form. I want the first string to be unbold, and the returned value to be bold. So i have a ppt template that I use to accomplish this, which contains a text box i refer to. the text box is set to Not-Bold by default, and I was wondering if I could set some font property within the Format$ portion to get where I want to go with this??

may be totally off, but just wondering

thanks
Justin

Comment: SQL has no font attributes so this is a presentation-layer issue. It is not by any stretch of the imagination an Access question.

Comment: oh...is the format$ function a part of SQL?? i didn't know that. i guess i just titled the question an access question because I am using an access form to fire the event, SQL statement to create the recordset that moves the data to ppt, and the rs!metric#43 was a part of that...though i didn't realize the Format$ was a part of SQL

Comment: Format() is not part of SQL, but if you use it in a SQL statement run within Access, the Access expression service takes care of handling its use. You said you're using it in a recordset, so that's a SQL context. I'm not sure if SQL executed from PowerPoint will utilize the Access/Jet/ACE expression service or not. If you used ODBC I'm sure it wouldn't, but with a DAO recordset, it's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: In any event, font is a presentation layer issue, and not a data retrieval layer issue.

Comment: ah....i see. well i didn't know if i was way off when asking, but i thought it may be possible. i understand though...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the format command, but you can use the text box object in power point and set the font and text and box.

This code is from inside of PP, but just modify it for automation:

```
Dim strT     As String
Dim sp       As Shape

strT = "Yes/No"

Set sp = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2)

sp.TextFrame.TextRange = strT
sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, 3).Font.Bold = True
sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, 3).Font.Name = "Arial"
sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, 3).Font.Size = 18
```

So, setting of the font, font name, and size is possbile.

Comment: yeah that works just fine! Thanks very much! I am actually already making the references just as you did above to pass the data, just needed to add .cahracter, etc! I appreciate it!